# How to determine if Daylight Saving Time is enabled or not in qnx?

Tags: c, timezone

I have done the following on a QNX Neutrino OS platform:

```
extern int daylight;
....
tzset();

printf("DST %s\n", daylight ? "enabled":"disabled");
printf( "TZ: %s\n", (tz = getenv( "TZ" )) ? tz : "default IST" );
```

And output is :

```
DST enabled

TZ: default IST
```

which is incorrect, even though it shows dst enabled but TZ is giving default value.

Whats wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Which part of your output is incorrect?

Comment: Perhaps QNX Neutrino OS will default to a system timezone if `TZ` isn't set. Perhaps DST is enabled in the system timezone. I don't know QNX. Does it have anything like `/etc/localtime` to set the system timezone?